# Parent light source to camera with specific distance and orientation

Tags: python, rendering, camera, light, parent

I'm working on a task that requires me to render 2D images of a 3D object from various angles.I've managed to write a script to move the camera around and render the images along with that. What I wanted to add was that the light object should be a fixed distance from the camera and should have a similar orientation as that of the camera(i.e the direction should be the same as the camera's optical axis). Is there any way in Blender to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints. On the light object use a "Child of" constraint using the Camera as target.

[image]

Comment: or.. just parent it?

Comment: Constraints will give you more options to choose from. I'm not sure exactly if the OP means with the Optical axis requirement.

Comment: Sure.. not meant to be a criticism!

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Yes, parenting would work as well.

Comment: @Pullup I did try this, but I can't set the distance between the light source and the camera. I want it to be specifically a fixed distance, which I set along with the orientation. What I meant regarding the Optical axis was that the point source must be facing in the same direction as that of the camera

Comment: Us a track to contsraint or a copy rotation constraint

Comment: @Pullup That sets the orientation but I'm not able to set the distance. I want the light source to be 10 meters from my camera, How do I set this?